# Convert datetime to timestamp in Eloquent Database select

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel's Eloquent Database Model in order to fetch a product from database:

```
$product = ProductModel
            ::with('authors')
            ->select(
                'products.id', 'products.title', 'products.release_date'
            )
            ->first();
```

The release_date is stored as datetime in the database which is fine. For a special purpose, I need to convert datetime to timestamp.

Is there a way to do this inside the select function?

e.g. `'products.release_date' AS convert(timestamp, products.release_date)` ?

Comment: show you data, what are you stored in `products.release_date`

Comment: I strongly recommend you to convert the date in the model, not in the query ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DB::raw()` in select method,  or `selectRaw()` as independent method.

**Link:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::raw("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(products.release_date, '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p'))")
```

this will return output in timestamp instead of datetime. i think this will do your job.